# Is there a C++ version of getc_unlocked( )?

Tags: c++, locking, istream, getc

While it seems that, in theory, `std::istream::get()` could be fast, in fact it isn't.  I believe that one reason is that some locking is done for every call to `std::istream::get()`, and that for single-threaded programs this isn't needed.  Is there an equivalent to `getc_unlocked` in C++?  Or perhaps some method of turning off this locking for (I presume) a `std::streambuf`, in C++?